# Tableau data source column name changed when using a duplicated view from database (Teradata)

Tags: teradata, tableau-api

I was using a view (VW_NEW_CUSTOMERS) in Teradata and all the column names had an underscore in it. The column names in tableau did not contain underscores.

For example:

```
Customer_Number (From Table View)
Customer Number (From Tableau Column Name)
```

Now I created a duplicate of the view (VW_NEW_CUSTOMERS_2), all the columns have the underscore in Tableau. So when I use replace data sources, the column name mapping is completely different from the above because of the underscores.

New Tableau fields from duplicated View:

```
Customer_Number (From Table View)
Customer_Number (From Tableau Column Name)
```

I would like to know why the underscores did not appear 1st time and it is now appearing when I duplicated the view. How can I rename the fields so that it comes like the 1st time? Should I do them manually now?

Note: Database columns were using aliases

Comment: Hardly a Tableau expert, but you can rename objects in the metadata grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this thread](https://community.tableau.com/s/question/0D54T00000C5kx8SAB/in-82-how-do-i-stop-tableau-from-renaming-all-my-fields), this isn't new, Tableau decided to start renaming fields some time ago. Not sure why it would have done on one of your data sources, but not the other.

Anyway, the exec summary, you may need to reset the field names of the version without the underscore, which should bring the underscore back into your data, making both data sources the same. To do this, copied from the thread:

"Version 9.3 and 10.1, you can select all the measures (and dimensions) in a worksheet, right click and "reset names" in two operations"

I think there's also a way to hack the xml to add the spaces to your copy, should that be preferrable. The thread covers hacking the xml to remove spaces, therefore I assume to add spaces do the same but in reverse.